# AWK - file sharing

Tags: awk

I have two files:

**File_1**

```
Head;track1;track2;track3;
date1;vol2;vol4;vol9;
date2;vol5;vol0;vol1;
date3;vol7;vol2;vol5;
```

**File_2**

```
Head1
trackV1 track1
trackV2 track2
trackV3 track3
```

I want to share File_1 and the result stored in separate files. With File_1 I write separately ($1, $2), ($1, $3), ($1, $4). The names of new files will be retrieved from the first column File_2 (trackV1, trackV2, trackV3). I want to create these files:

**trackV1**

```
Head track1
date1 vol2
date2 vol5
date3 vol7
```

**trackV2**

```
Head track2
date1 vol4
date2 vol0
date3 vol2
```

**trackV3**

```
Head track3
date1 vol9
date2 vol1
date3 vol5
```

I tried different solutions, but do not work:

```
awk 'BEGIN { while(getline < "File_1"){split($0, tab, ";"); print  $(getline a < "File_2") > tab[1] tab[2]}}'
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put it in `foo.awk`. Usage (note the order of the files)
`awk -f foo.awk File_2 File_1`

```
BEGIN {
    # fields separator
    FS=";"
}

# skip a first line in the "names file"
NR==FNR && NR==1 {next}

NR==FNR {
    # read "names file"
    split($1, aux, " ")
    name[aux[2]]=aux[1]
    next
}

FNR!=NR && FNR==1{
    # read a header of the "data file" and create output files
    split($0, head)
    for (i=2; i<NF; i++) {
       print "Head", head[i] > name[head[i]]
    }
    next
}

{
    # populate output files
    for (i=2; i<NF; i++) {
       print $1, $i >> name[head[i]]
    }
}
```